# how to get file directory when open with or send to event?

Tags: vb.net

How do I get a file's directory when open with or send to event happens? 
I want it like media player, the application can get the file name & path when the user runs it with Open With.

Answer (score 0):

The filename will be pased on the command line to your application, so you can access it by either

```
Module MainModule

  Sub Main(cmdArgs As String())

    Dim fileName as string = cmdArgs(0)

  End Sub

End Module
```

For a console application, or by

```
 Dim args As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
 Dim fileName As String = args(1)
```

For a GUI application.

Note that when using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`, the first element in the array will be the full path to your executable, so you need to access the second element to get the file name. In the first example, `cmdArgs` will only contain the file name parameter.

To get the directory name containing the file, you can use

```
Dim path as String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)
```